# algorithm to see if some sign(s) of terms will sum to zero

Tags: algorithms

I was trying to develop an algorithm so see if a given set of terms $a,b,c,d$ can sum to zero given any possible combination of signs $+/-$ on those terms.

How does one compute how many distinct summations exist for any given set?

And can you give me some *hints* as to how the algorithm itself might look?

Comment: If this is a programming assignment then I suspect that the question wants you to do brute-force search on all options and simply count those which sum to zero - there are only $2^3=8$ (or $2^4$ if the first element in the sum can get a minus sign) different options

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Are you looking for an elegant "shortcut" requiring number theory or something?

Comment: Actually, this was so I could check that some energies sum to zero - I found a problem where I suspected they couldn't.  Yes, I can brute force this, but some elegant shortcut would be much appreciated!

Comment: I recently heard about this problem of coin-weighing where one of the coins is fake: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_puzzle. The solution involves testing subgroups... Maybe you can use similar concepts in testing if these "balance out" to zero? Anybody have ideas and/or is good at isomorphism problems?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing $ \pm a \pm b \pm c \pm d$, there are $4$ signs, and each can be $+$ or $-$, so that makes $2^4$ possibilities.

But for a large number of terms, trying every possibility is a very inefficient algorithm.   Depending on the nature of the terms, you might do better with a Dynamic Programming algorithm.  If $S_k$ is the set of all possible sums of $(\pm)$ the 
first $k$ terms, and $t_{k+1}$ is the $k+1$'th term, then $S_{k+1} = (S_k + t_{k+1}) \cup (S_k - t_{k+1})$.